# Can screenshots of sports sites be used on a blog?

Tags: copyright

I'm writing a blog on hockey news, analyzing things such as trade rumors, what players would fit on what teams, and what players are performing better than others. To do this, I want to use screenshots of statistics from Yahoo Sports. I would crop the image to get the picture of the player with their name and statistics of this season (not the whole page). The screenshots are related to what is discussed in my posts and it's a non-commercial blog. Does this fall under fair use? The country I am in has signed the Berne Convention. I would also provide links back to the webpage I took the screenshot from.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, however, Yahoo has been known to sue. Call a copyright lawyer first. It would be money well spent. Lawsuits can start at $10k just to start a defense.

Comment: From Yahoo's [TOS](https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/):  `Any unauthorized reproduction, publication, further distribution or public exhibition of the materials provided on the Yahoo Services, in whole or in part, is strictly prohibited.` The photos of players are probably licensed to Yahoo, so you might be violating other copyrights as well. "Fair use" is also primarily a U.S. legal doctrine. Would you get sued? Unlikely, however I'd suggest using lower resolution/thumbnail copies of the photos (like search engines do). Player stats are in the public domain...

Comment: but would suggest adding them yourself instead of copying them too, which would strengthen Yahoo's case (likely in the form of a cease and desist letter at first).